# HTML everything I type becomes a hyperlink

Tags: html

I have made a site using css and html and in the main body underneath my nav bar whenever I try and make a normal paragraph, everything within the paragraph becomes a link to the contact.html webpage!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Ace Moldels</title>
 <meta name="description" content=“A website that sells radio controlled model cars" />
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="head">
 
 <div class="header_content">
  <center><img src="images/pic1.jpg"></center>
 
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</li>
    <li><a href="cars.html">CARS</li>
    <li><a href="boats.html">BOATS</li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</li>
   </ul> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="headerbreak"></div>
</div>

<p> Greetings hello there</p>

<p> Greetings hello there</p>
```

Comment: You're not closing your `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the `<a href="...">` tags:

```
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="cars.html">CARS</a></li>
<li><a href="boats.html">BOATS</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you very much. Been stuck for ages on that!!  Cheers, Robbie.

Answer (score 0):

Close the anchor tags.

Example:

```html
<a href="your-link-here">Text of the link</a>
```

Comment: Yeah its working now, many thanks to you, really appreciated, cheers Robbie